# Add a class= attribute to an <svg> that is already defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have icons:

```
//myicons.js
import React from "react";

export const ico = {
    someIcon:
        <svg ... >
           ...
        </svg>,
```

And a component that uses some icon:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ico } from "./myicons";

export class MyIcon extends Component {
    render () {
        return ico[this.props.which];
    }
}
```

And somewhere that uses the icon:

```
//some render func
return (
    <div ... >
        <MyIcon which="someIcon"/>
        ...
    </div>
);
```

Suppose I were to add a css class:

```
<MyIcon which="someIcon" className="blahblah" />
```

..how do I get the DOM to end up containing `<svg class="blahblah"` i.e. how do I add the blahblah class given in `<MyIcon className="blahblah"` to the `class=` attribute of the `<svg` returned by `ico[this.props.which]` ?

If it helps, this is what ends up being returned from the render:

[image]

Comment: (I know I could wrap the `ico[...]` like `<div className={this.props.className}>ico[...]</div>` but I'm curious if I can programmatically edit the svg fragment that `ico[...]` returns..)

Comment: React treat the className in MyIcon component as prop, so you cant assign a className in a component. you can wrap it in a div with a className.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it like this:

```
import React from "react";

const getIconWithClass = (type, className) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "iconA":
      return <svg className={className}>iconA</svg>;
    case "iconB":
      return <svg className={className}>iconB</svg>;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};
class MyIcon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { which, className } = this.props;
    return getIconWithClass(which, className);
  }
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyIcon which="iconA" className="bla-bla" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I did wonder if I'd have to pass it into the icon provider, thanks!